# datawind ubislate 9ci tablet computer hanging on boot

Tags: android

I purchased a new tablet Datawind Ubislate 9ci. It is a 9 inch no-bluetooth tablet. Details:

- Android 4.1.1
- Rock chip RK2928
- Linux kernel version 3.0.36

I was trying to install CWM through mobile odin and ROM manager but my tablet was not supported so I downloaded build.prop editor from Google play and changed it to some other cwm recognizable model viz. Samsung, nexus etc. When I was doing the above mentioned procedure, suddenly my tablet is coming up to bootloading and hanging there only and not opening

I went to recovery and tried to  Do wipe data factory reset but failed to get opened after boot Android system recovery(3e) has the following options

1. Reboot system now
2. Apply update from ADB
3. Apply update from external storage
4. Update rkimage from external storage
5. Wipe data factory reset
6. Wipe cache partition
7. Recovery system from back up

I tried to do wipe data, factory  Reset 2-3 times but still hanging at boot. I had not made any back up  Before this bootloop and also tried hard reset by pressing needle at the back.

Somebody help me to get rid of this problem and also tell me how to unlock bootloader

Answer (score 0):

"wipe data factory reset" only wipes the *data* partition. You need to fix the *system* partition. When my build.prop got messed up, I could modify it through adb, though that required a custom recovery (CWM). Other options are using the stock recovery to flash a stock firmware image, or using whatever flashing tool that works for that tablet, if one exists.

Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with that specific brand/model enough to offer more specific advice. There's a [related thread with firmware flash instructions for the 7C on xda-devs](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2250226). You might want to post there with your issue as well; they *might* be able to help.

If you can't perform a firmware flash and are unable to find a valid update image, you might be out of luck.